# Couldn't modify a field in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have below list with dicts:

```
categories=[
{'id':0,'value':8,'name':'Banking'},
{'id':1,'value':5,'name':'Home'},
{'id':2,'value':2,'name':'Travel'},
{'id':3,'value':4,'name':'Movies'},
{'id':4,'value':7,'name':'Hiking'},
{'id':5,'value':9,'name':'Food'},]
```

Am trying to traverse through all the values from above list and update them as below :

```
    for cat in categories:
        if(cat['value']==2):
            cat['value']=1
        if(cat['value']==3):
            cat['value']=4
        if(cat['value']==4):
            cat['value']=8
        if(cat['value']==5):
            cat['value']=12
        if(cat['value']==8):
            cat['value']=40
......
(from 2 till 10 in if condition)
```

The problem with this approach is that, 
for example, `cat['value']` for name Banking is 8
so above if condition will set the value to 40.

and later in the loop, `cat['value']` for Movies become 8 from 4, and it is later gets updated as 40 .. (by now it messed up the `cat['values']`)

So, this approach of updating is incorrect for sure.

How can I update `cat['values']` of my list based on these multiple conditions?

May be I can frame the if conditions as another list if required like this
`[{2:1},{3:4},{4:8},{5:12},....]`

Could you please help me with an approach on how I can get my `cat['values']` updated as per conditions above ?

Comment: use `elif` (read "else if") instead of `if` except for the first `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also write your conversions into a dict and then access the dict by the old value and overwrite with the value of the dict.

```
conversions ={2:1,3:4,4:8,..}
for cat in categories:
    cat['values']=conversions[cat['values']]
```

Comment: also you can use lamda, but a bit hard to understand

Comment: I really like your answer, but if OP does not know `elif` he might have troubles understanding this. Maybe adding a explanation will help.

Comment: Hi Ali Nikneshan, is 'conversions' better solution than if elif conditions?  Which is the best one?

Comment: I prefer dict searching (conversions) over elif. it done in single shot instead of running many if/elif. even when your conditions are more complex you still can use dictionary for mapping if key then value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali Nikneshan!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `elif` to update the value once ([official doc on control-flows](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html))

```
for cat in categories:
    if cat['value'] == 2:
        cat['value'] = 1
    elif cat['value'] == 3:
        cat['value'] = 4
    elif cat['value'] == 4:
        cat['value'] = 8
    elif cat['value'] == 5:
        cat['value'] = 12
    elif cat['value'] == 8:
        cat['value'] = 40
```

PS: you do not need the () around the `if` in python

Comment: Thanks a lot Altoyr!, I will try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `elif` for the 2nd and subsequent comparisons:

```
if cat['value'] == 2:
    cat['value'] = 1
elif cat['value'] == 3:
    cat['value'] = 4 
...
```

Alternatively, you can remap the values using a dictionary:

```
values = {2: 1, 3: 4, 4: 8, 5: 12, 8: 40}
cat["value"] = values[cat["value"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a series of `if` statements, make it a single `elif` chain.

```
    for cat in categories:
        if(cat['value']==2):
            cat['value']=1   
        elif(cat['value']==3):
            cat['value']=4
        elif(cat['value']==4):
            cat['value']=8
        elif(cat['value']==5):
            cat['value']=12
        elif(cat['value']==8):
            cat['value']=40
```

(Alternatively, you could use the `continue` statement once you have found the value to move on to your next category.)